# Cleaning var output on ansible to use it on a file

Tags: json, ansible

im trying to use ansible to set dinamicly a few parameters on ssh_config, the data is taken from the output of a var, bat the problem is, when i use the var it cames to the file with all the ansible output.

What i have.

```
- name: Get f_ips
  register: f_ip
  debug:
    msg: "{{ var.var.outputs | json_query(\"[?output_key=='f_ips'].output_value\") }}"

- name: put the f_ip on ssh_config
  replace: 
    path: /tmp/ssh_config
    regexp: 'ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p CHANGEME'
    replace: 'ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p "{{ f_ip }}"'
```

This works as expected, it register the ip from the vm, but when i do the replace it goes to the file like this.

```
Jumpbox .
Host 10.xx.xxx.*
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p "{'msg': [['11.11.11.11']], 'failed': False, 'changed': False}
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/2.pem

Host CHANGEME
  Hostname CHANGEME
  User root
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/ansible-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist 5m
```

So, instead of putting just the ip, it puts all the string of ansible output, to clarify, this is how i see the var in first place on the ansible execution.

```
    "msg": [
        [
            "11.11.11.11"
        ]
    ]
}
```

So, its there some way to just register the ip of that output on send it to my file ?

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
replace: 'ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p "{{ f_ip.msg.0.0 }}"'
```

Comment: Ty Vladimir, thats what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

The working code.

```
- name: FIP
  register: f_ip
  debug:
    msg: "{{ var.var.outputs | json_query(\"[?output_key=='f_ips'].output_value\") }}"

- name: ssh_config
  replace:
    path: /tmp/ssh_config
    regexp: 'CHANGEME'
    replace:  "{{ f_ip.msg[0][0] }}"
```